# Kubernetes stateful mongodb: What is right string or how to connect to mongodb of running istance of statefulset which has service also attached?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

Here is my config of YAML (all PV, Statefulset, and Service get created fine no issues in that). Tried a bunch of solution for connection string of Kubernetes mongo but didn't work any.

Kubernetes version (minikube):
1.20.1

Storage for config:
NFS (working fine, tested)

OS:
Linux Mint 20

YAML CONFIG:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: auth-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 250Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: manual
  nfs:
    path: /nfs/auth
    server: 192.168.10.104
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    name: mongo
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    role: mongo
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  serviceName: mongo
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: mongo-persistent-storage
      spec:
        storageClassName: manual
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteMany"]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 250Mi
```

Comment: Aleady tried

mongodb://<service_name>:27017 => not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found few issues in your configuration file. In your service manifest file you use

```
  selector:
    role: mongo
```

But in your statefull set pod template you are using

```
labels:
        app: mongo
```

One more thing you should use `ClusterIP:None` to use the headless service which is recommended for statefull set, if you want to access the db using dns name.

Comment: Thank pulak, i will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

To all viewers, working YAML is below

```
right connection string is: mongodb://mongo:27017/<dbname>
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: auth-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 250Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: manual
  nfs:
    path: /nfs/auth
    server: 192.168.10.104
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    name: mongo
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    app: mongo
  clusterIP: None  
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  serviceName: mongo
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: mongo-persistent-storage
      spec:
        storageClassName: manual
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteMany"]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 250Mi
```